# Issue with left join, printing the right column

Tags: php, sql

I have this query,

```
$sql_sektori= "SELECT formas.*,sektor_servisi.sektori,sektor_servisi.id_sektori
FROM formas
LEFT JOIN sektor_servisi ON formas.sektori = sektor_servisi.id_sektori
WHERE id=$id order by sektor_servisi.id_sektori asc";
```

The issue is:
I have a column named `sektori`, both in forma table and in the `sektor_servisi` table.
Now, i need to print the sektori column from `sektor_servisi` table.

How can i do it?

```
$row[servis_sektori.sektori]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use aliases:

```
SELECT formas.sektori AS f_sektori, sektor_servisis.sektori AS s_sektori
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

echo $row['f_sektori'], $row['s_sektori']
```

Comment: Or use a purely numeric fetch mode... but aliases are easier to work with.

Comment: This won't work...
SELECT formas.*,sektor_servisi.sektori sektor_servisis.sektori AS s_sektori,sektor_servisi.id_sektori FROM formas LEFT JOIN sektor_servisi ON formas.sektori = sektor_servisi.id_sektori WHERE id=$id order by sektor_servisi.id_sektori asc

Comment: "won't work" how? once you've aliased a field, you should use the alias in the other portions of the query as well, so your join would be `... ON f_sektori = sektor_servisi.id_sektori` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could alias the sektor_servisi.sektori column i.e.

```
$sql_sektori= "SELECT formas.*,sektor_servisi.sektori AS sektori2,sektor_servisi.id_sektori FROM formas LEFT JOIN sektor_servisi ON formas.sektori = sektor_servisi.id_sektori WHERE id=$id order by sektor_servisi.id_sektori asc";
```

You can then just use

```
$row[sektori2]
```